# BigQuery copy command

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been going through the book Google BigQuery Analytics. On page 354 it states that a table copy completes in less than a minute irrespective of table size. Is this correct? How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's test that assessment.

I have a [2TB table with 55 billion rows](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2018?tab=details):

[image]

I will ask BigQuery to make a copy of it:

[image]

The requested job was completed in 55 seconds - less than a minute:

[image]

So let me answer the 2 questions above:

- *On page 354 it states that a table copy completes in less than a minute irrespective of table size. Is this correct*?

The book is old, but the answer is still "yes".

- *How is it possible*?

BigQuery is powered by

[image: unicorns and rainbows]

Comment: Got it. If the copy/snapshot only stores modified data, am I billed for the storage that the source table uses (in your example the 2.25 TB) or just for any data that is modified in or appended to the copy?

Comment: The question in the previous comment looks like "if A then B?"... I can't answer that question, because I'm not a saying that A is a fact.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. Am I charged for the copy as well as the original? In your example, am I charged 2.25 TB of storage or 4.5 TB of storage?

Comment: I would say yes. Double the data, double the storage costs.